# How to raise Procedure Cache Hit Ratio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, memory

I have a SQL Server 2012 instance with 96 GB of RAM that has the Buffer Cache Hit Ratio consistently at 100% and the PLE consistently over 500,000, so memory is obviously not a problem.

However, my monitoring tool shows the Procedure Cache Hit Ratio is usually in the low 90% range, dropping as low as 70% between 10pm and 7am when the user load is minimal. There are no significant nightly maintenance jobs that run other than a full backup which only takes about 6 minutes. The Plan Cache Size doesn't vary significantly over the course of 24 hours, staying around 7 MB.

If I run DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('SQL Plans'), it drops the Plan Cache Size to less than 1 MB, but seems to have no effect on the Procedure Cache Hit Ratio. We have not tried "optimize for ad hoc workloads", mainly due to risk aversion and a concern that if freeing the cache didn't make a difference, changing that setting may not either.

While I have no user complaints about performance, I'd like to understand this better.

What might be causing the nightly dip in the ratio?

What can I do to improve the Procedure Cache Hit Ratio?

Comment: Did you referred to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57313/how-to-improve-procedure-cache-hit-ratio

Comment: what version of SQL Server 2012 are you running? How big are the databases? Is beeing a SQL Server the only role of the server? Or do you have also files or anything else stored?

Comment: Can you check the size and use counts from the cache, for example using the query in here: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/

Comment: JamesZ, I can (and did). Currently: Adhoc is 60,948 plans using 1,479 MB, of which 40,937 plans using 917 MB are single-use. That's why I tried the DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('SQL Plans'). It drops the Plan Cache Size to less than 1 MB, but seems to have no effect on the Procedure Cache Hit Ratio.

Comment: If you clear plans from the cache, that would make your cache hit ratio go *down*, not up.

Comment: Aaron, mu understanding is that clearing just the ad hoc plans from cache shouldn't drop the hit ratio because those plans are never looked for once they are created as the statements that caused those plans to be generated only execute once. On my servers, freeing those plans from the cache doesn't cause the Buffer Cache Hit Ratio or the Procedure Cache Hit Ratio to move either way.

Comment: If dropping all ad-hoc plans reduces the plan cache to less than 1MB, what is left after you issue the command?

Comment: Running the command DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('SQL Plans') *is* what drops the ad-hoc plans and reduces the plan cache to < 1 MB. Of course, it then immediately starts climbing again. But it never grows larger than 7 MB.

Comment: Shanky: Yes I did. But my circumstances are different - SQL Server 2005 and 2012 act quite differently. In part, I am trying to understand why the ratio is dropping so low. Getting it higher would be great, but since I don't seem to have a performance problem, it would be a bonus.

Comment: Ray: The server is SP1 (I've been unable to get management to agree to let me restart the instance to install SP2). It is the only instance on the box, and it is used for nothing else. There are three databases, with the mdfs totaling about 80 GB.